# Empty div wont grow

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get familiar with css animations using codepen.io, but I can't seem to make the div expand in size. It seems like there is a simple solution that I am just overlooking. Can anyone help?

codepen: http://codepen.io/trebey/pen/PqRZKK

```css
@import 'bourbon';
@import 'neat';

div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.circle-1 {
  max-height: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  border-radius: 20%;
  backgrouund: #000;

}

.circle-2 {
  max-height: rem(300);
  max-width: rem(300);
  border: 1px solid #333;
  border-radius: 20%;
  backgrouund: #333;
}

.square-1 {
  max-height: rem(300);
  max-width: rem(300);
  border: 1px solid #333;
  backgrouund: #000;
}

.square-2 {
  max-height: rem(300);
  max-width: rem(300);
  border: 1px solid #333;
  backgrouund: #000;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <body>
    <div class="square-1"></div>
    <div class="circle-1"></div>
    <div class="circle-2"></div>
    <div class="square-2"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues. Instead of specifying just `max-width`, you should specify a `width` (and height too). It's an inline-block element that sizes to its contents, but since there is no content, you should help it a little.

Also, you misspelled `background`.

Lastly, `rem(300)` doesn't work. `rem` (the root em) is a unit and can be used like `em` or `px` as I did below for `.circle-2`, but not as a function. I think you copied that from a SASS, SCSS or LESS example.

```css
@import 'bourbon';
@import 'neat';

div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.circle-1 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  border-radius: 20%;
  background: #000;

}

.circle-2 {
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  border-radius: 20%;
  background: #333;
}

.square-1 {
  height: rem(300);
  width: rem(300);
  border: 1px solid #333;
  background: #000;
}

.square-2 {
  height: rem(300);
  width: rem(300);
  border: 1px solid #333;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <body>
    <div class="square-1"></div>
    <div class="circle-1"></div>
    <div class="circle-2"></div>
    <div class="square-2"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, GolezTrol, the 'max' was the problem. rem() is a function from bourbon that I imported, so it works.